# How to cancel ngrx effect from executing if the user has logged out

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an action that is dispatched in order to load data when a user logs in. It's caught by an effect as follows:

```
  getData$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.getData),
      exhaustMap(() => {
        return this.apiService.getData().pipe(
          map(result => {
            // Update state with loaded data
            return Actions.loadedData({
              data: result,
            });
          }),
          catchError(errorRes => {
             // Handle error
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
```

When the user logs out, I want to reset the state, so i've added an action that when dispatched will reset the state to the initial state. But the following sequence poses an issue:

1. User logs in, action to load data is dispatched
2. Action is caught by the effect, makes the service call
3. User logs out, action to reset state is dispatched and state is reset
4. Service call returns and loadedData is dispatched to update the state with the data

Because the effect is running while the logout action is dispatched and the state is reset, the loadedData action is called to update the state with the data. How can I avoid both the service call being made, and the subsequent loadedData action from running in the effect if the user has logged out.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change from `exhaustMap` to `switchMap`
([How to cancel http request with switchMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958362/how-to-cancel-http-request-with-switchmap)) and additionally use an observable to receive cancel signal. In your case a source for this observable will be a selector that selects current authentication status. If an observable returns 'logged in', you continue with the request and return `Actions.loadedData` action. If an observable returns 'logged out', you return `Actions.noop`.